# Guardar una imagen de GoogleMaps en servidor con ASP.NET MVC 4 y C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

Estoy haciendo un sitio en el que uso Google Maps API, genero coordenadas y busco un sitio específico, luego tomo una captura del sitio con `html2canvas` para generar una imagen en un `<img>`, mi pregunta es:

¿Cómo puedo llevar esta imagen al controlador?

Este es el `div` en el que está la imagen:

```
<div id="googlemapimage">
    <img id="googlemapbinary" width="640" height="480"/>
</div>
```

En mi controlador estoy usando funciones para transformar la imagen como quiero, pero ingresaban por `httppostfilebase`, ¿puedo usar la imagen del `div` en el controlador? Si es así, ¿cómo?

Comment: Hola Oscar, bienvenido a StackOverflow es español, te aconsejo que a la hora de hacer una pregunta o respuesta, mantengas una buena Ortografía, para que así todos puedan entender de que hablas.

Comment: Agrego a lo que menciona @WilfredoP visites este [link para mas info](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Me parece una buena pregunta, sin embargo no comparto la idea de almacenar la imagen en la base de datos, en lugar de ello, se podría guardar en una carpeta de subida de archivos así como lo hacen diversos CMS. Cabe mencionar que almacenar imágenes en base de datos hacen que el peso de la misma aumente considerablemente. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

1. Vamos generando el Canvas a partir de la imagen que tienes en ese div con la función getBase64. Lo hice de la manera más genérica, tendrás que darle a jugar con las variables para conseguir lo que deseas.

   ```
   <html>
   <head></head>
   <script>

   function getBase64Image() {
        var img = document.getElementById("LaImagenAprocesar");
        // creamos un canvas en blanco
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        // Copiamos el contenido de la imagen al canvas
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // Obtenemos el data-URL con formato de la imagen
        // Firefox soporta PNG y JPEG. Ojo aqui, hay que revisar 
        // el img.src al formato original, ten cuidado si utilizas image/jpeg,
        // porque  esto le dara un re-encode a la imagen

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        return alert(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));
    }
   </script>
   <body>

       <div>
           <img id="LaImagenAprocesar" src="unaimagen.png" alt="">

           <button type="button" onclick="getBase64Image()">mostrar data-url</button>

       </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. Con esa cadena, utilizar un Ajax `Request` o un `post` para enviarlo al controlador. Esa variable de nombre "miCadenaEnBase64" debes obtenerla del método anterior y bueno, te presento al Ajax usando jQuery, sería así:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       cache: false,
       async: true,
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://example.com/MiControlador/Create",
       data: {
           imageData: miCadenaEnBase64 
       },            
       success: function () {
           alert('Se ha guardado la imagen!');
       }
   });
   ```
3. Aquí la implementación en el controlador

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Create(string imageData)
   {
       string fileName = "NombreDelArchivo.png";
       string fileNameWitPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/FolderToSave"), fileName);

       using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
       {
           using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
           {
               byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
               bw.Write(data);
               bw.Close();
           }
           fs.Close();
       }

           return RedirectToAction("Index");

   }
   ```

Por cierto, revisa tener permisos de escritura en dicha carpeta.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas aplicando esta tecnica

[HTML5 Canvas Save Drawing as an Image](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/)

o sea usas el `toDataURL()` entonces estas asignando al `img` una imagen cuyo encode es base64.
Puedes validar esto que comento con este ejemplo

[HTML5 Canvas: toDataURL()](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/todataurl.html)

Alli veras como se genera la imagen en base64 y se asigna al img, es asi como la tomarias del `img` para enviarla al controller.

[Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)

Basicamente debes poner en una variable en javascript el contenido base64, pero quitando la parte que define el tipo de imagen.

Entonces en asp.net mvc defines un action con un parametro del tipo `string` que recibira la imagen en base64.
Para invocar al action usar `$.ajax`, `$.post` y en los parametros enviarias la imagen como string.

En el controller usarias [Convert.FromBase64String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx) para obtener el array de byte de la imagen.