# ¿Cómo inserto una imagen a una tabla en SQL Server desde ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, base-de-datos, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy creando un formulario y en un campo debo subir una imagen para poder hacer una validación, pero he intentado de varias formas y nada, apreciaría que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. Dices que has intentado algunas formas y no funciona, si dejas esos intentos será más fácil saber cómo orientarte :)

Comment: Busca en el sitio antes de preguntar, es un caso muy común, aquí hay una pregunta relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3273/822